# Curl isn't keeping cookies

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl succefuly to simulate user on several website but I have a problem on a new one.
I'm handling cookie with this code:

```
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies");
```

Usualy that creates a cookies file as you know, but for this website it doesn't, I don't even have a empty file.
However, by putting CURLOPT_HEADER to TRUE I see I receive some "Set-Cookie" values.

I really don't know how it is possible, if someone have an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Does the user running the script have permissions to create/write files in whatever working directory that would result in the file being written to?  Try a temp folder path and see if that works.

Comment: sorry I'm just stupid, the cookie file is created on curl close, what I didn't call...